# Как локализовать ошибку в плейбуке или роли ansible?

Tags: отладка, ansible

Рефакторю роли в ansible. После некоторых изменений в очередной раз запускаю привычным способом (в точности такая команда уже не раз срабатывала):

```
ansible-playbook -s -v -i hosts/testing someplaybook.yaml
```

Получаю портянку стектрейса. Непонятно, можно ли как-то из этого локализовать ошибку?

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook", line 324, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "/usr/local/bin/ansible-playbook", line 264, in main
    pb.run()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/__init__.py", line 310, in run
    play = Play(self, play_ds, play_basedir, vault_password=self.vault_password)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/play.py", line 194, in __init__
    self._tasks      = self._load_tasks(self._ds.get('tasks', []), load_vars)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/play.py", line 664, in _load_tasks
    data = utils.parse_yaml_from_file(include_filename, vault_password=self.vault_password)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/utils/__init__.py", line 780, in parse_yaml_from_file
    process_yaml_error(exc, data, path, show_content)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ansible/utils/__init__.py", line 713, in process_yaml_error
    %s""" % (path, mark.line + 1, mark.column + 1, before_probline, probline, arrow)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Менял содержимое всего одной роли — расставил теги. Сейчас закомментировал их все, но ошибка воспроизводится. Я не могу опубликовать саму роль, но это и не нужно. Вопрос не о том, где у меня ошибка (я всегда могу сделать `git checkout` и всё будет хорошо), а о том, **как искать эти ошибки, используя стектрейс или что-то ещё.**

Comment: А переменная окружения LANG чему равна ? Буквально вчера пробовал ответить на один вопрос, там как раз питон был и он похожую ошибку выдавал о декоде, пока я экспериментировал с  LANG пытаясь вырубить UTF8. LANG=en_US помог (для не UTF)

Comment: @Mike: `ru_RU.UTF-8`. Но её я тоже не менял.

Comment: @Mike: ошибка была в лишних или недостающих пробелах (несколько раз натыкался на такое). Но общего способа решения так и не нашел.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очень мощное средство отладки плейбуков -- это как раз `git diff`, самого сколько раз спасало. ;)

Если же сконцетрироваться именно на стектрейсе ансибл, то самая полезная строка стектрейса - самая последняя, всё сразу становится на свои места. Если непонятно - то гуглим, вряд ли вы столкнётесь с чем-то уникальным, что ещё не спрашивали на so. )

Посмотрим конкретный пример - ваш:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position
>   10: ordinal not in range(128)

Вот, например, сходу [аналогичный вопрос на so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561923/unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xef-in-position-1). 
И причина тоже в общем-то понятна - каким-то образом у вас в коде оказался символ не той кодировки (в том вопросе на so грешат на то, что терминал был выставлен не в utf-8; у вас возможно при копипасте из другого приложения взялось не то). 
И понятно, почему вы не можете ничего поделать с ошибкой - ищете логическую, закомментировали все теги, а то, что ошибка не в алгоритме, не в коде, а в самом формате - и не подумали бы.

Вот вам ещё [пример вопроса на so со стектрейсом](https://serverfault.com/questions/665684/dict-as-value-for-yaml-key-in-an-ansible-task), там тоже всё прозаично и понятно, но можно и погуглить подробности - [вот пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751322/python-2-attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-strip).

---

А теперь, к сожалению, о грустном:

Больше ничего полезного из стектрейса не вытащить.

Как программист, вы должны хотя бы в общих чертах понимать разницу между языком программирования императивным (программа как набор команд/инструкций, шаг за шагом изменяющих состояние программы) и декларативным языком описания (например, html и yaml). 
С ходу нагуглилась, например, [такая статья на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/231897/).

Плейбуки ансибл - это файлы на языке Yaml + шаблонизатор Jinja2, по сути это декларативщина всё.

А стектрейс - это понятие из области императивных ЯП (какие функции вызывались по стеку), в нашем конкретном случае - описание состояния машины, которая выполняет наши декларативные описания.

В 99,99% случаев для вас стектрейс ansible бесполезен, разве что вы являетесь разработчиком ядра ansible и активным контрибутором ансибл на гитхабе.

Причина проста: ошибки при выполнении - это в основном наши ошибки в описании конфигурации, а не в самом движке ансибла. А посмотрите на стектрейс - вы хоть что-нибудь видите там от своих файлов или только общие места типа `self`, `play_basedir` и `vault_password=self.vault_password`?

PS Недавно была статья на хабре про тестирование плейбуков, дополню до кучи ответ ([часть 1](https://habrahabr.ru/company/centosadmin/blog/303762/), [часть 2](https://habrahabr.ru/company/centosadmin/blog/304814/)) - основная идея в том, что плейбук через CI запускается на docker. Но это больше автоматизация процесса. У вас вопрос немного о другом, упор на траблшутинг - как разобраться в том, почему сломалось и как.

PPS Дополню ответ. Каждый шаг выполнения скрипта - это отдельный скрипт, который загружается на удалённый сервер и там отрабатывается. Из этого файла часто можно выжать больше детальной информации (наибольший интерес вызывает фвыа). Например, содержимое файла `/home/<username_ansible_connected>/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1478975838.41-114286257956022/command`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ZIPLOADER_PARAMS = '{"ANSIBLE_MODULE_ARGS": {"_ansible_version": "2.1.2.0", "_uses_shell": true, "_ansible_no_log": false, "_raw_params": "rsync -a user@vm5234271843336.hostname:/asdf/databases/ /databases/vm5234271843336/", "_ansible_verbosity": 3, "_ansible_syslog_facility": "LOG_USER", "_ansible_selinux_special_fs": ["fuse", "nfs", "vboxsf", "ramfs"], "_ansible_diff": false, "_ansible_debug": false, "_ansible_check_mode": false}}'
```